# Error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type -CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have some errors to my code and I still don't understand why it does not work.

I have the following code snippet:

```
void insertBefore(List *lista, Node **node, Node *newNode)
{
    newNode->prev = (*node)->prev;
    newNode->next = (*node);
    if((*node)->prev == 0)
        lista->first = newNode;
    else
        (*node)->prev->next = newNode;
    (*node)->prev = newNode;
}
```

And I call it as:
`insertBefore(lista,lista->first, newNode);`

And the error is :

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

What I tried and works(no errors but crashes when I debug):

```
void insertBefore(List *lista, Node **node, Node *newNode)
    {
        Node *anotherNode = (*node)->prev;
        newNode->prev = (*node)->prev;
        newNode->next = (*node);
        if((*node)->prev == 0)
            lista->first = newNode;
        else
            anotherNode->next = newNode;
        (*node)->prev = newNode;
    }
```

---

Here are the structures I use:

```
typedef struct NodeT
{
    struct nodeT *prev;
    struct nodeT *next;
    int key;
}Node;
typedef struct ListT
{
    Node *first;
    Node *last;
    Node *current;
}List;
```

---

Now, my question is: is there any issue when the compiler parses? I really don't figure it out.

Comment: The type of `lista->first` is `Node *` not `Node **`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch the capitalization!

```
typedef struct NodeT      /* uppercase N */
{
    struct nodeT *prev;   /* lowercase N */
```

`NodeT` and `nodeT` are different identifiers